# Annotation of root parent on django recursive model

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a recursive model Case (model has a self reference called parent), and I want to annotate a queryset Cases with the root parent.

So if I have a root A with child B which has a child C, i want the queryset containing all three to have a reference to A. I have created sql that accomplished this for a single Case, but I cannot grasp how to annotate a queryset with it. 
I am experimenting with a subclass of django.db.models.Func, but can't make it work.

Model:

```
class Case(CoreModel):
    ... fields ...
    parent = ForeignKey(
        'Case', 
        verbose_name=ugettext_lazy("Parent case"), 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
)
```

SQL query that works:

```
query = '''
        WITH RECURSIVE Ancestors AS (
              SELECT id, parent_id FROM core_case m where id = %(expressions)s
              UNION ALL
              SELECT m.id, m.parent_id
              FROM Ancestors 
              JOIN core_case m on m.id=Ancestors.parent_id
            )
        SELECT id, parent_id FROM Ancestors WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    '''
```

current attempt at a Func subclass:

```
class RootCase(Func):

    template = query

    def __init__(self, *expressions):
        super(RootCase, self).__init__(*expressions, output_field = IntegerField())
```

When testing this

```
cases = (
    Case
    .objects
    .filter(customer__company=514)
    .annotate(root=RootCase(7401))
 )
```

It fails:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH"
```

---

Progress:
I am now able to annotate a queryset with the query, but I cannot get the reference for every Case passed to the query

```
cases = (
    Case
    .objects
    .filter(customer__company=514)
    .annotate(root=RawSQL(query, (7401,))
 )
)
```

This works, but is always annotating with the root parent of 7401

```
cases = (
    Case
    .objects
    .filter(customer__company=514)
    .annotate(root=RawSQL(query, (OuterRef('pk'),))

 )
)
```

This fails with:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'OuterRef'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to insert the reference to the outer `Case` in the sql, and then postgres was then able to perform the annotation for each `Case` model instance.

```py
annotate_root_case_query = '''
    WITH RECURSIVE Ancestors AS (
          SELECT id, name, number, parent_id FROM core_case m where id = case_id
          UNION ALL
          SELECT m.id, m.name, m.number, m.parent_id
          FROM Ancestors 
          JOIN core_case m on m.id=Ancestors.parent_id
    )
    SELECT {field} FROM Ancestors WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    '''

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    root_case__number=RawSQL(
        annotate_root_case_query.format(field='number'), ()
    )
)
```

`case_id` is the `Case.id` to find the root for